# 1. jQuery doesn't work properly / 2. responsive issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive, effect

The first problem is that I linked the jQuery CDN to my html file, wrote the jQuery effect code (I want the text to fade in after page loads) but all it does is just hiding the text.
Second problem is that I'm trying to do fully responsive site, and every section should be 100vh, but when I shrink the window to less than iPhone 6 Plus resolution the images and text from the other sections start to overlap on other sections etc. How do I fix this? I'm a total beginner and I'd love to hear some criticism to improve.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fade").hide(0).delay(300).fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Gotham A, Gotham B, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 960;
  height: 100vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#welcome-screen {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  padding: 0 7%;
}
.heading {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.heading-span {
  display: block;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-transform: none;
}
.scrolldown-button {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
a {
  color: #000000;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
a:hover {
  color: #d09800;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#about {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 30px;
}
p {
  display: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.content-heading-span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: -20px;
  color: #d09800;
}
.contact-btn {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #000000;
}
.photo {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.copyright {
  text-align: center;
  color: #cccccc;
}
.phone {
  display: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cloud.typography.com/6493094/7214972/css/fonts.css">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="welcome-screen">
    <div class="heading fade">
      <h1><span class="heading-span">Hi! My name is</span>
      <strong>John Doe</strong>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="scrolldown-button">
      <a href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div id="about">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x250" class="photo"></img></span>
        <p><span class="content-heading-span"><strong>About me</strong></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget bibendum odio, eget varius tortor. Etiam imperdiet, sem in faucibus convallis, justo purus rutrum magna, ut
          lacinia ex tellus sit amet lectus. Curabitur tempor imperdiet laoreet. Quisque magna magna, tempus a nibh vitae, maximus malesuada mi. Nulla a justo dolor. Nullam risus nisl, vulputate vel arcu id, viverra finibus mauris. Donec porttitor lectus
          ut augue vehicula, vitae vehicula turpis eleifend. Proin eu quam at odio consectetur tincidunt. Proin eget elit id purus lacinia tincidunt. Nam at urna est. Quisque viverra nisi eu molestie accumsan. Ut at porttitor sem, quis viverra massa.
          Nulla odio libero, dictum a diam euismod, rhoncus efficitur lectus. Suspendisse eu mi vel diam euismod fermentum at et.</p>
        <a href=""><strong>Download my resume</strong></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="blabla">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p><span class="content-heading-span"><strong>Lorem Ipsum sit dolor amet</strong></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget bibendum odio, eget varius tortor. Etiam imperdiet, sem in faucibus convallis, justo purus
          rutrum magna, ut lacinia ex tellus sit amet lectus. Curabitur tempor imperdiet laoreet. Quisque magna magna, tempus a nibh vitae, maximus malesuada mi. Nulla a justo dolor. Nullam risus nisl, vulputate vel arcu id, viverra finibus mauris. Donec
          porttitor lectus ut augue vehicula, vitae vehicula turpis eleifend. Proin eu quam at odio consectetur tincidunt. Proin eget elit id purus lacinia tincidunt. Nam at urna est. Quisque viverra nisi eu molestie accumsan. Ut at porttitor sem, quis
          viverra massa. Nulla odio libero, dictum a diam euismod, rhoncus efficitur lectus. Suspendisse eu mi vel diam euismod fermentum at et.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="blabla2">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p><span class="content-heading-span"><strong>Proin eget elit</strong></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget bibendum odio, eget varius tortor. Etiam imperdiet, sem in faucibus convallis, justo purus rutrum magna,
          ut lacinia ex tellus sit amet lectus. Curabitur tempor imperdiet laoreet. Quisque magna magna, tempus a nibh vitae, maximus malesuada mi. Nulla a justo dolor. Nullam risus nisl, vulputate vel arcu id, viverra finibus mauris. Donec porttitor
          lectus ut augue vehicula, vitae vehicula turpis eleifend. Proin eu quam at odio consectetur tincidunt. Proin eget elit id purus lacinia tincidunt. Nam at urna est. Quisque viverra nisi eu molestie accumsan. Ut at porttitor sem, quis viverra
          massa. Nulla odio libero, dictum a diam euismod, rhoncus efficitur lectus. Suspendisse eu mi vel diam euismod fermentum at et.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="contact">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <p><span class="content-heading-span"><strong>consectetur tincidunt</strong></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget bibendum odio, eget varius tortor. Etiam imperdiet, sem in faucibus convallis, justo purus rutrum
            magna, ut lacinia ex tellus sit amet lectus. Curabitur tempor imperdiet laoreet. Quisque magna magna, tempus a nibh vitae, maximus malesuada mi. Nulla a justo dolor. Nullam risus nisl, vulputate vel arcu id, viverra finibus mauris. Donec porttitor
            lectus ut augue vehicula, vitae vehicula turpis eleifend. Proin eu quam at odio consectetur tincidunt. Proin eget elit id purus lacinia tincidunt. Nam at urna est. Quisque viverra nisi eu molestie accumsan. Ut at porttitor sem, quis viverra
            massa. Nulla odio libero, dictum a diam euismod, rhoncus efficitur lectus. Suspendisse eu mi vel diam euismod fermentum at et.</p>
          <span><p>E-mail:</p></span>
          <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com" class="contact-btn">test@gmail.com</a>
          <p>mobile:</p>
          <p class="phone">235 635 123</p>
          <div class="copyright">
            <p>Copyright @ 2017 by <a href="index.html">John Doe</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're including jQuery twice. It's not the cause of your issue but it certainly won't be helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".fade").hide(0).delay(300).fadeIn(500)` targets elements with a class of `fade` but none of your elements have a `fade` class. You can also just hide those elements with CSS, then display them using JS. I changed `body` to have `opacity: 0;`, then apply your jQuery to add a class of `.ready` to `body`, which will trigger `opacity: 1;` and the effect will transition/fade in with the `transition` line on `body`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".heading").delay(300).removeClass('fade');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Gotham A,Gotham B,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform:uppercase;

}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color:#9e9e9e;
  }
section {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 960;
  height:100vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#welcome-screen {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:#ebebeb;
  padding:0 7%;
}
.heading {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.heading-span {
    display: block;
    color: #8e8e8e;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-transform:none;
}
.scrolldown-button {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size:20px;
}
a {
  color:#000000;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.15s;
}
a:hover{
  color:#d09800;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#about {
  width: 100%;
  min-height:100vh;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100vh;
  padding:30px;
}
p {
  display:column;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.content-heading-span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-left:-20px;
  color:#d09800;
}
.contact-btn {
  font-size:2em;
  color:#000000;
}
.photo {
  margin-bottom:3em;
}
.copyright {
  text-align:center;
  color:#cccccc;

}
.phone {
  display:column;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-top:0px;
  font-size:2em;
  color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cloud.typography.com/6493094/7214972/css/fonts.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <section id="welcome-screen">
    <div class="heading fade">
      <h1><span class="heading-span">Hi! My name is</span>
      <strong>John Doe</strong>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="scrolldown-button">
      <a href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
  <div id="about">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/250x250" class="photo"></img></span>
      <p><span class="content-heading-span"><strong>About me</strong></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget bibendum odio, eget varius tortor. Etiam imperdiet, sem in faucibus convallis, justo purus rutrum magna, ut lacinia ex tellus sit amet lectus. Curabitur tempor imperdiet laoreet. Quisque magna magna, tempus a nibh vitae, maximus malesuada mi. Nulla a justo dolor. Nullam risus nisl, vulputate vel arcu id, viverra finibus mauris. Donec porttitor lectus ut augue vehicula, vitae vehicula turpis eleifend. Proin eu quam at odio consectetur tincidunt. Proin eget elit id purus lacinia tincidunt. Nam at urna est. Quisque viverra nisi eu molestie accumsan. Ut at porttitor sem, quis viverra massa. Nulla odio libero, dictum a diam euismod, rhoncus efficitur lectus. Suspendisse eu mi vel diam euismod fermentum at et.</p>
      <a href=""><strong>Download my resume</strong></a>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="blabla">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p><span class="content-heading-span"><strong>Lorem Ipsum sit dolor amet</strong></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget bibendum odio, eget varius tortor. Etiam imperdiet, sem in faucibus convallis, justo purus rutrum magna, ut lacinia ex tellus sit amet lectus. Curabitur tempor imperdiet laoreet. Quisque magna magna, tempus a nibh vitae, maximus malesuada mi. Nulla a justo dolor. Nullam risus nisl, vulputate vel arcu id, viverra finibus mauris. Donec porttitor lectus ut augue vehicula, vitae vehicula turpis eleifend. Proin eu quam at odio consectetur tincidunt. Proin eget elit id purus lacinia tincidunt. Nam at urna est. Quisque viverra nisi eu molestie accumsan. Ut at porttitor sem, quis viverra massa. Nulla odio libero, dictum a diam euismod, rhoncus efficitur lectus. Suspendisse eu mi vel diam euismod fermentum at et.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="blabla2">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p><span class="content-heading-span"><strong>Proin eget elit</strong></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget bibendum odio, eget varius tortor. Etiam imperdiet, sem in faucibus convallis, justo purus rutrum magna, ut lacinia ex tellus sit amet lectus. Curabitur tempor imperdiet laoreet. Quisque magna magna, tempus a nibh vitae, maximus malesuada mi. Nulla a justo dolor. Nullam risus nisl, vulputate vel arcu id, viverra finibus mauris. Donec porttitor lectus ut augue vehicula, vitae vehicula turpis eleifend. Proin eu quam at odio consectetur tincidunt. Proin eget elit id purus lacinia tincidunt. Nam at urna est. Quisque viverra nisi eu molestie accumsan. Ut at porttitor sem, quis viverra massa. Nulla odio libero, dictum a diam euismod, rhoncus efficitur lectus. Suspendisse eu mi vel diam euismod fermentum at et.</p>
    </div>
<div id="contact">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p><span class="content-heading-span"><strong>consectetur tincidunt</strong></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget bibendum odio, eget varius tortor. Etiam imperdiet, sem in faucibus convallis, justo purus rutrum magna, ut lacinia ex tellus sit amet lectus. Curabitur tempor imperdiet laoreet. Quisque magna magna, tempus a nibh vitae, maximus malesuada mi. Nulla a justo dolor. Nullam risus nisl, vulputate vel arcu id, viverra finibus mauris. Donec porttitor lectus ut augue vehicula, vitae vehicula turpis eleifend. Proin eu quam at odio consectetur tincidunt. Proin eget elit id purus lacinia tincidunt. Nam at urna est. Quisque viverra nisi eu molestie accumsan. Ut at porttitor sem, quis viverra massa. Nulla odio libero, dictum a diam euismod, rhoncus efficitur lectus. Suspendisse eu mi vel diam euismod fermentum at et.</p>
      <span><p>E-mail:</p></span>
     
     <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com" class="contact-btn">test@gmail.com</a>
      <p>mobile:</p>
      <p class="phone">235 635 123</p>
    <div class="copyright">
      <p> Copyright @ 2017 by <a href="index.html">John Doe</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Re: fixing the layout issues on smaller screens, what you want to do is re-position things either so that you use relative units that scale to various screens, or you want to look in to CSS @media queries. What you do is resize your browser(s) until the layout breaks, and at whatever width/height the layout breaks, introduce a CSS @media query at that "breakpoint" that changes the layout of elements that overlap or break the UI of the site. Here's a good reference on media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Oh, I'm really sorry. I erased the .fade class from my div with "heading" class (the first one after .welcome-screen div and forgot to put it back when pasting my code here (edited it). It doesn't work when I put it back anyways. All it does is hiding the element, but it doesnt fade it in.

Comment: @TomaszCzechowski edited my post to fade `.heading` instead

Comment: Yeah but have you got any ideas on why is my way not working? And when I changed your effect to last longer it doesn't appear to change (neither changing css duration nor jquery delay works). I'm really sorry for bothering you but I'm really trying to understand it.

Comment: @TomaszCzechowski your content isn't fading in because `.fade` is a class of a bootstrap mixin css file you linked to called "vendor-prefixes.less" and that defines `.fade` as `opacity: 0;`. You can use a different class instead, or you can work with that class and use `$.fadeTo()` instead of `$.fadeIn()` in your jQuery. `$.fadeIn()` only affects `display: none;`. `$.fadeTo()` affects the `opacity` value.

Comment: So all it took was just changing the name of the effects class? It's my second problem I posted here thats solution was awfully easy and I couldn't figure it out by myself for like whole day haha. The only part I don't understand is about those bootstrap mixins linked to called "vendor-prefixes.less". Can you give me link where I can read about that? I mean, I understand that there are some built-in bootstrap effects but where can I find some more informations about that? And again: Thank you Michael for saving my life twice! You're the man!!

Comment: @TomaszCzechowski sweet np! I don't use bootstrap or know much about it, but those CSS files are included with bootstrap. You can find references to the classes on http://getbootstrap.com. You can find references to `.fade` specifically on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/